# CVOpenGLESTexture - is it worth it

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Should I use `CVOpenGLESTexture` methods, or is there something better ? On GLES 3, I can use PBO (like in classic OpenGL 3/4), but will `CVOpenGLESTexture` be faster or slower. So far, I am targeting ES 2, but regarding my code desgin I would like to know If I should do GLES 3 special version of my tetxure class, or I can go without performance hit with `CVOpenGLESTexture`.

[CVOpenGLESTexture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreVideo/Reference/CVOpenGLESTextureRef/Reference/reference.html) link to API

*PS: Answers of type "try and you see" are not very helpfull. I dont have time to code everything, so maybe someone has already tried and from that point I would like to know their oppinions.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried, either. But I suspect `CVOpenGLESTexture` gets some special treatment in the lower levels of the OS & hardware, so it's likely to remain fastest. (Good general design guideline: if you're depending on something very platform-specific, like the ability to pull frames from the camera directly into GL in hardware, the most platform-specific API is probably the one most tuned for performance.)

Also, ES3 is only supported on A7 hardware (iPhone 5s, iPad Air, iPad mini Retina, and whatever comes after those). In the unlikely event there's a performance gain to be had from PBOs, it's probably too small to justify the burden of maintaining and tuning both a CV and PBO path for as long as you plan to support iPhone 4/4s/5, iPad 2/3/4, etc.